# List new & featured products in Magento homepage

Tags: magento, magento-1.4

I put this code in my home.phtml, but nothing is shown. I took this snippet of script from product/new.phtml :

```
<?php if (($_products = $this->getProductCollection()) && $_products->getSize()): ?>
<?php $i=0; foreach ($_products->getItems() as $_product): ?>
    <?php if ($i>15): continue; endif; ?>

    <div>
            <a href="<?php echo $_product->getProductUrl() ?>" title="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_product->getName()) ?>">
                <img class="home-page-img" src="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'small_image')->directResize(40,50,3); ?>"  alt="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_product->getName()) ?>" />
            </a>
    </div>

    <div>
    <p><a class="product-name" href="<?php echo $_product->getProductUrl() ?>" title="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_product->getName()) ?>)"><?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_product->getName()) ?></a></p>
    </div>
<?php $i++; endforeach; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

How can I make it to display on the homepage? I have set products to be new products within certain date. Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it by adding something like this to your layout update (CMS -> Pages -> Manage Content, select Home page, go to Design section)

```
<reference name="content">
<block type="catalog/product_new" name="home.catalog.product.new" alias="product_new" template="catalog/product/new.phtml" after="cms_page"/>
</reference>
```

Comment: Hi Zifius , thanks for your reply. Oh my, I didn't realize I'm missing that out. Thanks so much! May I know what should I put in to have featured products listed as well? Appreciate your help

Comment: By the way, I copied the codes from new.phtml to home.phtml, the scripts will not work. Do you have any idea why is it so? Thanks!

Comment: For the featured list it's all the same except you need to create new attribute, please refer to this article: http://inchoo.net/ecommerce/magento/promotion-and-random/ Also you shouldn't edit home.phtml directly

Comment: When I click on `catalog/product/new.phtml` I get not found page, how can I build these page?